# Google map does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show user current location using google map but it shows current location for 1 second and then shows

> Sorry! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps
>   correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

What is wrong?

My code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="download/css/core.css">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Using GeoLocation API With Google Maps - Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <section class="container">
        <h2>Using GeoLocation API With Google Maps - Demo</h2>
        <section id="wrapper">
            Click the allow button to let the browser find your location.

            <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
            <article></article>
            <script>

                function success(position) {
                    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
                    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
                    mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
                    mapcanvas.style.width = '600px';

                    document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

                    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                    var options = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: coords,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                        },
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: coords,
                        map: map,
                        title: "You are here!"
                    });
                }

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
                } else {
                    error('Geo Location is not supported');
                }
            </script>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-8196211-5']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the browser console say is the error? Most likely an API Key missing.

Comment: Either as @Dandy said or something else. Check the console for more information

Answer (score 1):

Add key like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?Key=MyKey&sensor=true"></script>
```

You can create your key from here:[generate map api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: I see `<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` in the code - it could be the OP removed the key?

Comment: No, he has not added the key!

Comment: Possibly or removed on purpose to not share it here?

Comment: Yes may be, but If so then he can post like I've posted `key=Mykey`

Comment: I try also using key, but same problem!

Comment: @Akib67 you should add script in the head not in body